# ArgumentError in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, arguments, argument-error

I want to connect two entity (project and issues) and Rails says some error message, but I don't know, what should I do. Can you help me fix it, please? Thanks a lot.

[image: Error screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your are trying to do, but it looks like you have a nested resource and therefore want to pass an array to `form_for`, but you are actually passing two separate objects. Change:

```
<%= form_for(@project, @project.issues.build) do |f| %>
```

to:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.issues.build]) do |f| %>
```

With this change you'll pass one array for `form_for`, instead of two arguments.

Comment: `@issue` is `nil`. What does your controller look like?

Comment: IssueController - https://gist.github.com/4001328
ProjectController - https://gist.github.com/4001332

Comment: @medy75: Instead of `if @issue.errors.any?` use `if f.object.errors.any?`. And everywhere else in your `_form.html.erb` replace `@issue` with `f.object`.

Comment: @medy75: I told you before; it should be `<%= form_for([@project, @project.issues.build]) do |f| %>`, not `<%= form_for([@project, @issue]) do |f| %>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used nested resources like this:

```
resources projects do
  resources issues
end
```

If you used that, try make your form like this:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @issue]) do |f| %>
```

and in your IssueController :

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
  @issue = @project.issues.build(params[:issue])
end

def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]
  @issue = @project.issues.create(params[:issue]
end
```

and run again to see something happen. Hope this help.

Comment: You are right with resources. But after change _form to @issue and controller, it writes: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: Issue - https://gist.github.com/4001616
Project - https://gist.github.com/4001621

Comment: with your routes, if you want to show issues of a project, your URL will like: `projects/:project_id/issues`, so in `index` action of your controller, you have to find a project with project id and display all issue of that project, means you willl have: `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])` and `@issues = @project.issues` . Which step you have erros, when create new issue?

Comment: It makes that error, when I want to see some project (http://localhost:3000/projects/3) - undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class.

Comment: I think in your view, you don't have a `@projects` variable passed from controller to view, for example, if you want to list all project in index page you have to pass an `@projects = Project.all` in your index action. Then in your view you can use @projects to loop every link for every project.