# Rails:ArgumentError in MethodTypes#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to make an edit for ruby on rails, but it shows me the argument error about the edit. I am confused about this question.

Then, I have tried to put the different argument into index.html.erb However, it still does not work. For example `m.id` and `m`

This is index.html.erb

```
<% @methodtypes.each do|m| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%=m.name %></td>
      <td><%=m.desp %></td>
   </tr>
   <%= link_to "Edit", edit_method_types_path(m.id) %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Create Method", new_method_types_path %>
```

This is my controller file:

```
class MethodTypesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @methodtypes = MethodType.all
    end

    def show
      @methodtype = MethodType.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end   

    def create
      @methodtype = MethodType.new(method_params)
      @methodtype.save
      if @methodtype.save
        redirect_to  method_types_path
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

    def edit
        @methodtype = MethodType.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @methodtype = MethodType.new
    end 

private

    def method_params
      params.require(:method_type).permit(:name, :desp)
    end
```

This is my edit page which is edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @methodtype do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_area :name %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :desp %>
    <%= f.text_field :desp %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The result should show that I can edit my text. but, it shows the ArgumentError in MethodTypes#edit. Does someone can give me some suggestion, I do not know how to fix that.....

Comment: Can you post your edit page?

Comment: @Velu Sure, I have added edit page code.

Comment: Can you refer this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195737/argumenterror-in-rails

Comment: does rails routes gives edit_method_types as output

Comment: @Velu, ok, I will look at this. oh, It also tells me First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: @Nithin, it told me ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MethodTypesController#edit
Couldn't find MethodType without an ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wrong edit url path**

It should be **<%= link_to "Edit", edit_method_type_path(m.id) %>** instead of <%= link_to "Edit", edit_method_types_path(m.id) %>

Also check your routes file It seems you are defining

```
 resource: method_types
```

Change to

```
 resources: method_types
```

Comment: when I type rake routes, it shows me the path which is edit_method_types GET    /method_types/edit(.:format) method_types#edit. And I have tried your way, it does not work.

Comment: Check your routes file

It seems you are defining  resource: method_types   

Change to 

resources: method_types

Answer (score 0):

`<%= link_to "Edit", edit_method_types_path(m.id) %>` should be `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_method_type_path(m) %>`, note that **type** is in singular.

Run `rails routes -g method_type` to confirm it.

Also, change the `MethodType.find_by_id(params[:id])` to `MethodType.find(params[:id])` in the controller.

Btw, you are calling `save` twice in your `create` method:

```rb
def create
  @methodtype = MethodType.new(method_params)
  @methodtype.save # delete this line
  if @methodtype.save
    redirect_to  method_types_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: I used to use find instead of find_by_id. It does not work. It told me ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MethodTypesController#edit
Couldn't find MethodType without an ID. Therefore, I need to use find_by_id.

Comment: Bear in mind that `find_by_id` returns `nil` when no record is found and `<%= form_for @methodtype do |f| %>` will fail anyway.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I have deleted @methodtype.save. But I still confused to fix this problem

Comment: Please, paste the definition of `method_types` in `schema.rb`. Where is the actual link pointing to? `http://localhost:3000/method_types/???/edit`

Comment: ，There is definition in method_type.  If clicking edit button, the link will show http://127.0.0.1:3000/method_types/edit.1

Comment: I found there is an error in my route. It should be  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_method_types_path(id: m) %>

Comment: It seems you are defining routes by hand, pls check [resource](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource)